# How to validate a row inside ILIST class property in a class that implements IValidatableobject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am migrating my current asp.net site to mvc 3. The old asp.net page implements repeater control and can validate each rows in code behind.

I created a Model class and inherits IValidatableObject. See below code:

```
public class ManageInstitutions : IValidatableObject
{
        public ManageInstitutions() { }

        public int InstitutionID { get; set; }
        public string InstituteName { get; set; }
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public string EAddress { get; set; }

        public IList<InstitutionIPBL> IPDetailsList { get; set; }

        //Validation Function
        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            foreach (var item in IPDetailsList)
            {
                 if (item.IPPart1.Length == 0 && item.IPPart2.Length == 0 && item.IPPart3From.Length == 0 && item.IPPart3To.Length == 0 && item.IPPart4From.Length == 0 && item.IPPart4To.Length == 0)
                  {
                        //How to return ValidationResult that will identify which row got an error????????? 
                  }
            }
        }


}
```

The `InstitutionIPBL` is a class that came from the old asp.net business layer. I re-use this class to represent as a property in my model.

I need to know how can I identify which row got the error. I am using this syntax to check if the field is valid: `Html.ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField("[Field Name]"))`

My problem is how to identify which row got an error as per the illustrated comment on the above code.

Anyone? Please advise. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Validating arrays and collections is a tricky thing in MVC due to a lack of support.

When it comes to validating a single element within an IEnumerable, ICollection, IList, etc. you have to include the index of each element within the HTML element and validation index within ModelState (at least as the most common workaround without having to create custom model binders).

So if your model looks like:

```
public IList<string> List { get; set; }
```

And your markup looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="List[0]" />
<input type="text" name="List[1]" />
<input type="text" name="List[2]" />
```

Then you will notice that each element has its own index which is what MVC's form provider uses to bind the input to the model.

Thus when you go to write your validation, you need to make sure to include the index of the violating element (code expanded for simplicity):

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(List[i])) {
                yield return new ValidationResult(i + 
                                  ": You forgot to fill in the box.",
                                  new[] { "List[" + i + "]" });
            }  
        }
}
```

Then when you go to write out your validation messages:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("List[1]")
```

Now as far as actually looking up WHICH element has the validation message, you would need to look through ModelState to get the key of the invalid element.

```
ModelState.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("List") && x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
          .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Something like this could be made into an HtmlHelper where the ModelState can be accessed through:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> 
      GetValidationMessagesForGroup(this HtmlHelper helper, string keyStart) {
    return helper.ViewData.ModelState.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("List")
                         && x.Value.Errors.Count > 0).Select(x => x.Key);
}
```

And call it in your view:

```
@{
   foreach(string key in Html.GetValidationMessagesForGroup("List")) 
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(key)
}
```

For strongly typed objects, all you need to do to key them is add the property on the end.

```
Child[0].FirstName
```

It is important to remember that each of your properties for each element in your list will have its own entry.